# Shuffle the id of table to get details in android

Tags: android, database, shuffle

I have **student** table , which has four fiels **id, name, address** and **age**. In this table 50 student. My question is , How to shuffle the id and get that  id's details( id, name, address and age) and get the one id at a time and if i click the **next** button then next student details.

**DatabaseHeper.java**

```
 // I donot understand which code write in DatabaseHeper.java file 
 /*
public Cursor shuffleJokes(int [] id) {

        Cursor c = null;
    c = myDataBase.rawQuery("select _id,title,body from jokes where title ="
            + id, null);
    return c;
}*/

public void shuffleJokes(int [] ar) {       

Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
  // Simple swap
  int a = ar[index];
  ar[index] = ar[i];
  ar[i] = a;
}
```

**shuffleStudnt.java**

```
DatabaseHelper db;
Cursor cur
cur=db.shuffleArray(arrayofid);  // how to get arrayofid array which is id of student table
cur.moveToFirst();
```

I have problem, in how to get table id in array. Please give me best solution which code write in **DatabaseHeper.java** and **shuffleStudent.java** file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select a random student from the table every time you tap a button, right?

Then I would query all students, save them to an array and then select one randomly from that array everytime the user taps the button.

Comment: I know that, but how save the all student an array?

Comment: create a class "Student" with fields for id, name, address and age, create one "Student" for each entry in your database and then save them to an ArrayList<Student>