# shuffle in database table using id

Tags: android

How to shuffle id of database table of  sqlite in android. And display or retrieve data with respective shuffled id of table.

For example: In **programmer** table:
**id**: 1,2,3 and **level**: trainee, junior and senior respectively.

My intention is shuffle the these id with respective level. If first load id 2 with junior then if i click next it may b show 1 or 3 with receptive level and so on.

I am newbie in android . Thanks in advance.

Comment: [check here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831857/shuffle-the-id-of-table-to-get-details-in-android

Comment: you really need to change id's or just wana cursor with data in random order ? for 2. you can use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM()`

Comment: I want to shuffle these id not random.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a direct way for shuffling data in sqllite but you can do this by using following way ::

1. First Fetch the Ids from the DB.
2. then Shuffle using Java Collection API (for ex :: Collections.shuffle(shuffleList); )
3. Finally Update the DB with Shuffling list.

i hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

[Ajay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840802/ajay)'s solution is quite efficient, indeed.

Starting with the observation that we can retrieve the ids of a table (eg. count 5) based on a set:

```
select *
from table_name
where _id in (4, 1, 2, 5, 3)
```

we can come to the result that if we could generate the string "(4, 1, 2, 5, 3)", then we would have a more efficient way than RAND().

For example, in Java:

```
ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(rowsCount);
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    indices.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(indices, new Random());
String inClause = indices.toString();
inClause = inClause.replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');
```

If ids have gaps, then the initial arraylist "indices" is the result of an sql query on ids.